# Hash hostnames in $HOME/.ssh/config?

Tags: ssh, security, openssh

I know it's a good security measure to set `HashKnownHosts yes` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, which causes OpenSSH client to hash the hostnames in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. Now I want to hash the hostnames in `~/.ssh/config` as well for the same reason. Is it possible with OpenSSH on Ubuntu and Debian (and other Debian-derivatives)?

Answer (score 3):

No, most, if not all, places where you can have hostnames in `.ssh/config` also allow wildcards, and you can't realistically guess any wildcard-string that could potentially match your target hostname.

(This is completely leaving aside that there are many other configuration statements where hashing does not make sense at all, because you need to read the configuration, not just confirm it against something you already have.)